# predicate calculus , implication

Tags: artificial-intelligence, predicate, discrete-mathematics

I'm new in predicate , and AI in general , but I know that the implication means that it is false if the before "->" is true and after it is false , other wise it's true .

but how it's using  if I don't know the after "->" side ?

such that , the **parent(X, Y)** must be known to know if this predicate is false or true , although the  **parent(X, Y)** it's what we want to infer.

> ∀ X ∀ Y father(X, Y) ∨ mother(X, Y) → parent(X, Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this article on wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table). You have multiple choice there, you statement can be true but also false. This was also on udacity Ai course and they have just put it in a separate category, partially known. It is still better than unknown but you'll have to use something else.